# SystemTap Inter process communication

Tags: linux, filesystems, systemtap

I am considering using SystemTap for monitoring FileSystem activities on a production server.

How can I transfer data from the kernel module that SystemTap generates to another application? I only saw printf as a way of outputting data from SystemTap script, Is there some sort of socket interface?

Answer (score 0):

There is no network IPC support currently in systemtap.  However, ways include:

- `probe FOO { system("some_shell_command") }`  to enqueue execution of arbitrary shell script.
- `probe procfs.{read,write}("PATH") {}`  to export files in /proc that userspace applications can read/write to talk directly to the stap module.
- `stap --remote HOST ...` to execute stap modules remotely, and carry I/O back via ssh.
- Or use [named pipes](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html): `mkfifo tun`, open `tun` for read-only in the target app, then run `stap -o tun ...`.